# Assembly Loop Output Issue

Tags: loops, assembly

I am having an issue with this code snippet of a problem. My expected output is (after the intro):

Please enter an unsigned number: (user input)
.
.
.
Repeat ten times

The output that I am getting is :

Please enter an unsigned number: 10

10 <--- this is displaying instead of "Please enter an unsigned number: "

Any idea why this problem might be happening?

```
;getString should display a prompt, then get the user’s keyboard input into a memory location
    getString MACRO buffer
        push    edx             ;Save edx register
        mov edx, OFFSET buffer
        call    WriteString
        call    ReadString
        pop edx

    ENDM

    ;displayString should the string stored in a specified memory location. 
    displayString MACRO buffer
        push    edx
        mov edx, OFFSET buffer
        call WriteString
        call crlf

    ENDM



    .data
    intro_1 BYTE    "PROGRAMMING ASSIGNMENT 5: Designing low-level I/O procedures",0
    intro_2 BYTE    "Written by: Eric Walters",0
    intro_3 BYTE    "Please provide 10 unsigned decimal integers.",0
    intro_4 BYTE    "Each number needs to be small enough to fit inside a 32 bit register.",0
    intro_5 BYTE    "After you have finished inputting the raw numbers I will display a list",0
    intro_6 BYTE    "of the integers, their sum, and their average value.",0
    data_1  BYTE    "Please enter an unsigned number: ",0
    array   DWORD   10 DUP(?)




    .code
    main PROC

            ;Introduction
            displayString intro_1
            displayString intro_2
            displayString intro_3
            displayString intro_4
            displayString intro_5
            displayString intro_6
            push OFFSET array
            call getString1

            ;readVal


            exit
    main ENDP

    getString1 PROC


                push ebp
                mov ebp, esp

                mov ecx, 9
                mov esi, [ebp + 8]

                getString2:
                    getString data_1
                    mov [esi], eax
                    add esi, 4
                    call crlf
                    dec ecx
                    jmp getString2
                    ret



    getString1 ENDP








    END main
```

Comment: Please include the results of your debugging attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is in some parameter being inadvertently passed into read string pointing at the address where data_1 is stored.  For example, if edx is pointing at data_1 when you mov the OFFSET into it, and the WriteString is looking at edx for the address of the data to write, ReadString is looking at edx for the address to store the line in once it is read.  So the ReadString is overwriting your sentence in data_1 with the number you entered and an end of line marker.  Then the next time the WriteString PROC is called, it is reading in that number.

To fix this, create a .data? field called input_data or whatever you like, and point edx at it after the WriteString call but before the ReadString call.

Just an aside, but I also think you need to change your line after "dec ecx" to read "jnz getString2", not "jmp getString2".  Otherwise I cannot see you ever escaping the loop no matter what value ecx reaches.

EDIT:  Wait, I see, you have an array set up for that already.  I think you just need to point to it before calling ReadString.